# Targeting a tablet without using media queries

Tags: html, css, tablet

I'm just wondering if it is possible to target a tablet without using media queries. The reason I ask this is that I already using media queries but I have images that are grayscale on desktop and when hovered they change to the original colour. I have removed the grayscale when the device hits a certain size so it is fine on smaller tablets and mobiles but it is just a bit too small for the ipad and certain tablets when they are landscaped.

Is there any way to target the tablet to turn the filter off without touching the media queries?

Thanks in advance

The website in question is [www.garethjweaver.com](http://www.garethjweaver.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Mobile ESP framework; specifically the JavaScript one. It can detect individual devices or groups of devices such as tablets.

http://blog.mobileesp.com/

The method most pertaining to what you want to achieve is:

```
MobileEsp.DetectTierTablet();
```

It also allows you to pick specific groups of tablets by OS:

```
MobileEsp.DetectAndroidTablet();
MobileEsp.DetectWebOSTablet();
MobileEsp.DetectIpad();
MobileEsp.DetectMaemoTablet();
MobileEsp.DetectBlackBerryTablet();
MobileEsp.DetectOperaAndroidTablet();
```

A possible usage scenario:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.hand-interactive.com/js/mdetect.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {

        if(MobileEsp.DetectTierTablet()) { // if its a tablet this will be true

            $("html").addClass("isTablet"); // this will add the isTablet class to the HTML element

        }    
    });
<script>
```

The example above uses [jQuery](http://www.jQuery.com), which will make things easier for you if you are getting started with JavaScript. With that in place you just need to set up rules for your tablets in your stylesheet like this:

```
<style>
    body {
        max-width: 1200px;
    }
    .isTablet body {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

It also has other versions for ASP.NET and PHP so you can do the detection server side.

Here's a fiddle illustrating the functionality outlined above:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrissp26/wndqr/1/)**

Comment: OK thanks I will give it a look, I am a complete newbie when it comes to javascript though so I will more than likely ask more questions about this soon

Comment: There are plenty of usage scenarios on the site that you can copy and paste. Essentially what you can do is set a CSS class onto the HTML element of the page of "isTablet" and then prefix any tablet specific styles with that class.

Comment: So for instance instead of .isTablet body {max-width:100%;} it could be .isTablet.grayscale{filter:none;}. Would that work?

Comment: I tried what I did above, but it did not work, you can see the code on the website now. I didn't download the MobileESP, just put the link in the script src. I have a feeling that isn't right and that I may need to make a .js page for it? But then I look at your fiddle and all you did was use the link that I used

Comment: It actually works when I put it in a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/garethweaver/txb9T/) which is weird, so I must have the code wrong??

Comment: Have you included jQuery? and are you using the $(function() {}); to invoke your code? JSFiddle masks the jQuery ready event but you need an event to trigger the code you are running. Just wrap your code with this: $(function() { /* code goes here */ });

Comment: Here's a fiddle illustrating the invocation of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/chrissp26/txb9T/2/

Comment: I've ammended the script in my answer. I've had a look at your page, and the problem is the self executing function I used in my example. Replace your example with the script from my answer and all should work.

Answer (score 0):

I get that you don't want to touch the media query, but as far as I can see it feels like your problem can be solved by 
`@media  (orientation: landscape) { ... }`

You want to determine if it's a landscape view..right?

about other usages of media query [MDN:media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

if you really don't want to touch it, there is another option is to use javascript. But I think that will be make things more complicated.

Hope my answer helps..:)